# dotCloud custom node.js service nginx config

Tags: node.js, nginx, dotcloud

I setup a custom nodejs service using the https://github.com/dotcloud/node-on-dotcloud . But now it seems like it doesn't have nginx. How to setup nginx for a custom nodejs service?

Comment: This is quite old. Any acceptable solutions?

Comment: I tried Andy's answer, but couldn't make it work (maybe I messed something up). So I ended up setting an empty PHP service with nginx.conf in the root that proxies all requests to my node.js service.

Comment: Btw, is there any reason for using PHP service and not the static service?

Comment: No, I think there is no reason. I did it just because I found the answer on a forum where somebody used PHP service. I guess any service that has nginx would work.

Comment: @bvukelic Were you able to make it work with a static service?

Comment: No, actually, I had some problems with setting up Node.js so I gave up on dotCloud in the end.

Answer (score 0):

First, a cautionary statement: the dotCloud 'custom' service is still in beta. So the answer I give you now could change in the future.

When you create a 'custom' type nodejs service, your service container also has nginx available, but it is not running. To get nginx to run, you will need to:

1. Add an nginx.conf file to the root of your application.
2. Add a 'process' to your dotcloud.yml file to start up nginx:

   process: nginx -c your_configuration_file

where *your_configuration_file* is the full path to your nginx.conf

I hope that helps!

/Andy